# Evaluating my model with confusion matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to replicate `Lenet-5` neural network and I want to show the confusion matrix of my results to evaluate my results.

This is what I have done:

```
# Create the model
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=6, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(120,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(84,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax'))

# I categorize the data because I use categorical crossentropy
train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
val_labels = to_categorical(val_labels)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)
# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=0.1),
               loss='categorical_crossentropy',
               metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels,
                    epochs=10, batch_size=128,
                    validation_data=(val_images, val_labels),
                    verbose=2)
```

Since here I think (hope) it's all ok. Nos I want to evaluate the performance of my model.

First I plot the accuracy.

```
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label='accuracy')
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], label = 'val_accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epochs'); plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.ylim([0.85, 1])
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

[image]

Then I evaluate the accuracy and loss.

```
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images,  test_labels, verbose=2)
>>> OUT: test_acc: 0.9909999966621399, test_loss: 0.03354883939027786
```

Now I want to see the confusion matrix,

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

predictions = model.predict(test_images)
confusion = confusion_matrix(test_labels, predictions.round())
```

But I have this error:

> ValueError: multilabel-indicator is not supported

I though maybe problem was the categorized test data, but not. Can somebody help me? My objective now, is evaluate my model the best as possible (I'm newbie) and I thought the confusion matrix was a good idea.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`model.predict` returns the vector representation of the models output (e.g. `[0.1, 0.05, 0.0, 0.85]`, but `confusion_matrix` expects the label/class of the output (e.g. `3`).

You can get from the vector to the predicted label using the `np.argmax` function:

```
predictedLabels = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
```

You might have to use the same approach on the `test_labels` if they are one-hot-encoded.

P.S.: check out `ConfusionMatrixDisplay` for a nice display of the confusion matrix